# What class does ReadonlyArray inherit?

Tags: typescript

I have this code snippet in TypeScript:

```
const arr: ReadonlyArray<string> = [
    "123",
    "234"
];

arr.push("345");
```

TS compiler shows an error:

> `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'ReadonlyArray<string>'`.

Of course, it's clear that I cannot change/alter this array. The question is: what is the base class for `ReadonlyArray`? Does it inherit from standard `Array` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html
states that:

> TypeScript comes with a `ReadonlyArray<T>` type that is the same as
> `Array<T>` with all mutating methods removed, so you can make sure you
> don’t change your arrays after creation

If you want the source, head over to:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1121  (01.06.2022) - Search for "ReadonlyArray" if source file evolved.

(its definition is on the line 1121 in the current version).

Comment: that link is broken as the line numbers in the master file aren't static..

Comment: @Peter agreed. I added a date - the link itself and a CTRL+F+"ReadonlyArray" will give you the current correct line.